# on change solo funciona una vez event javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs

Estoy trabajando con la libreria [TimePicker](https://github.com/jonataswalker/timepicker.js),y angularjs, para empezar tengo un campo tipo text en donde con el boton  `Configurar hora` muestro el input y selecciono la hora,despues de eso la oculto con el botón `Ocultar` y al volver a clickear el botón `Configurar hora` pasa el error, y es que la segunda vez el evento `on('change')` ya no sucede, he tratado de solucionarlo con esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42601267/select-onchange-event-does-not-works-on-first-time), tratar de remover event listeners antes de llamarlo de nuevo pero no funciono, dejo un ejemplo en donde se replica el error:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){

    
    $scope.changevalue = () => {
      $scope.configurar = true;
      this.resetTime();
     
    }
    
    $scope.ocultar = () => {
      $scope.configurar = false;
    }
      
    this.resetTime = () => {
      setTimeout(function(){ 
          var timepicker =  new TimePicker('timePicker', {lang: 'en', theme: 'dark'});
  
          timepicker.on('change', function(evt) {
              // este evento solo sucede una vez
              console.log("evt",evt)
              var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
              evt.element.value = value;
          }); // fin on change
      }, 200);// fin timeOut
    }// fin resetTime

})
```

```css
*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0}._jw-tpk-container{position:absolute;width:250px;height:140px;padding:0;background:#fff;font-family:inherit;font-weight:400;overflow:hidden;border-radius:3px;box-sizing:border-box;max-width:250px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;line-height:1rem;font-size:1rem}._jw-tpk-container:after{content:" ";display:block;clear:both}._jw-tpk-container *,._jw-tpk-container :after,._jw-tpk-container :before{box-sizing:border-box}._jw-tpk-container *,._jw-tpk-container .active,._jw-tpk-container :focus,._jw-tpk-container :hover{text-decoration:none;outline:none}._jw-tpk-container._jw-tpk-dragging{opacity:.85!important}._jw-tpk-container._jw-tpk-dragging ._jw-tpk-header{cursor:-webkit-grabbing;cursor:grabbing}._jw-tpk-container ol{text-align:center;list-style-type:none}._jw-tpk-container ol>li{display:inline-block}._jw-tpk-container ol>li>a{display:inline-block;padding:3px 0;width:25px;color:inherit;border-radius:3px;border:1px solid transparent;font-size:1.2rem}._jw-tpk-container ol>li>a:not(._jw-tpk-selected):hover{cursor:pointer;border:1px solid #ccc;border-right:1px solid #aaa;border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;background:#f5f5f5;background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#e6e6e6,#f5f5f5);background:linear-gradient(#e6e6e6,#f5f5f5);box-shadow:0 2px 3px hsla(0,0%,86%,.8)}._jw-tpk-header{position:relative;font-weight:600;text-align:center;cursor:-webkit-grab;cursor:grab;line-height:1.875rem}._jw-tpk-header:after,._jw-tpk-header:before{content:"";display:table}._jw-tpk-header:after{clear:both}._jw-tpk-body{padding:2px 0}._jw-tpk-body:after,._jw-tpk-body:before{content:"";display:table}._jw-tpk-body:after{clear:both}._jw-tpk-hour{width:64.49275%;float:left;margin-right:1.44928%}._jw-tpk-minute{width:34.05797%;float:right;margin-right:0}._jw-tpk-dark{color:#212121;box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px #212121}._jw-tpk-dark ._jw-tpk-header,._jw-tpk-dark ol>li>a._jw-tpk-selected{color:#f5f5f5;background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#212121,#545454);background:linear-gradient(#212121,#545454)}._jw-tpk-blue-grey{color:#263238;box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px #263238}._jw-tpk-blue-grey ._jw-tpk-header,._jw-tpk-blue-grey ol>li>a._jw-tpk-selected{color:#cfd8dc;background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#263238,#4f6875);background:linear-gradient(#263238,#4f6875)}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
      
      <button name="button" ng-click="ocultar()">Ocultar</button>
      <button name="button" ng-click="changevalue()">Configurar hora</button>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="timePicker" data-ng-if="configurar"  ng-model="hora"     autocomplete="off">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, te recomendaría no llamar al timepicker desde otra función, el evento change ya va a estar a la espera de que el valor cambie.

Comment: @Eduardo como podría llamarlo? , Actualmente lo hago así por qué el input aparece y se oculta, lo que provoca cambio en el Dom, agradezco cualquier aporte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incluí la solución con JS puro, puesto que no he estudiado Angular pero el concepto es el mismo y su equivalente en angular debería funcionar igual.

Como verás no es necesario crear un timePicker y mucho menos añadir un eventListener cada que se hace click.

Se declara que tienes un timePicker y cada que den click en la caja lo muestras; esto ayuda incluso a conservar los valores previos mejorando la usabilidad de tu página

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

const timepicker = new TimePicker('timePicker', {
    lang: 'en',
    theme: 'dark'
  });

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {  

  $scope.changevalue = () => {
    $scope.configurar = true;
    timepicker.show();
  }

  $scope.ocultar = () => {
    $scope.configurar = false;
  }



  timepicker.on('change', function(evt) {
    var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
    document.querySelector("#timePicker").value = value;
  }); // fin on change



})
```

```css
*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

._jw-tpk-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 250px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  line-height: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem
}

._jw-tpk-container:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both
}

._jw-tpk-container *,
._jw-tpk-container :after,
._jw-tpk-container :before {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

._jw-tpk-container *,
._jw-tpk-container .active,
._jw-tpk-container :focus,
._jw-tpk-container :hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none
}

._jw-tpk-container._jw-tpk-dragging {
  opacity: .85!important
}

._jw-tpk-container._jw-tpk-dragging ._jw-tpk-header {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing
}

._jw-tpk-container ol {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none
}

._jw-tpk-container ol>li {
  display: inline-block
}

._jw-tpk-container ol>li>a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 0;
  width: 25px;
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  font-size: 1.2rem
}

._jw-tpk-container ol>li>a:not(._jw-tpk-selected):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e6e6e6, #f5f5f5);
  background: linear-gradient(#e6e6e6, #f5f5f5);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px hsla(0, 0%, 86%, .8)
}

._jw-tpk-header {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
  line-height: 1.875rem
}

._jw-tpk-header:after,
._jw-tpk-header:before {
  content: "";
  display: table
}

._jw-tpk-header:after {
  clear: both
}

._jw-tpk-body {
  padding: 2px 0
}

._jw-tpk-body:after,
._jw-tpk-body:before {
  content: "";
  display: table
}

._jw-tpk-body:after {
  clear: both
}

._jw-tpk-hour {
  width: 64.49275%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1.44928%
}

._jw-tpk-minute {
  width: 34.05797%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0
}

._jw-tpk-dark {
  color: #212121;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #212121
}

._jw-tpk-dark ._jw-tpk-header,
._jw-tpk-dark ol>li>a._jw-tpk-selected {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#212121, #545454);
  background: linear-gradient(#212121, #545454)
}

._jw-tpk-blue-grey {
  color: #263238;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #263238
}

._jw-tpk-blue-grey ._jw-tpk-header,
._jw-tpk-blue-grey ol>li>a._jw-tpk-selected {
  color: #cfd8dc;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#263238, #4f6875);
  background: linear-gradient(#263238, #4f6875)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">

    <button name="button" ng-click="ocultar()">Ocultar</button>
    <button name="button" ng-click="changevalue()">Configurar hora</button>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="timePicker" data-ng-if="configurar" ng-model="hora" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Como dije lo cambié con un poco de JS puro, pero igual debería funcionar si tú conoces su equivalente con las directivas de Angular.

Espero te sea útil

Comment: Gracias, lo resolvi con ```ng-show``` en lugar de ```ng-if``` justamente para no perder el componente con el id del timepicker